# Jenkins Kube agent cannot pull from git

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes

I am running Jenkins in Kubernetes (EKS), and can successfully pull git repos when running the jobs on the Jenkins master with the pipeline code

```
gitInfo = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: '*/master']],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                extensions: [[$class: 'CleanCheckout'], [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'config']],
                submoduleCfg: [],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'Gitlab', url: 'git@gitlab.test.com:USER/config.git']]
            ])
```

and it checks out fine.
However when I try and pull on a Jenkins kube agent it doesnt seem to be able to get the key from the master correctly. Using the exact same checkout code I get the error

```
using credential Gitlab
Cloning the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.test.com:USER/config.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.test.com,11.11.111.11' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
  Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
  Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

In working logs I would expect to see the name of the credential it is trying to use

```
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Git Lab key used to bootstrap Jenkins Master
```

Has anyone seen this problem before?

My container spec is

```
spec:
containers:
- name: jnlp
  image: jenkins/jnlp-slave
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  env:
  - name: POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
  - name: DOCKER_HOST
    value: tcp://localhost:2375
```

Update:
So it seems that something is stripping newlines off the end of the id_rsa key in the credentials store.
I am using Jenkins Config as Code to add it from the AWS Parameter Store, so I think it is something going wrong here, as if I dump the contents of the secret from Parameter store and copy and paste that into the credential through the Jenkins UI the job works....

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by JCasC not being able to get the Parameters from AWS, so the Jenkins Credentials were corrupt (blank).

Debugged by running cat on credentials.xml and decrypting the credential in the script console

```
println(hudson.util.Secret.decrypt("{XXXXXXXX}"))
```

I have no idea how the master is able to clone from Git with the blank credential, but even in the UI it was showing as valid :/

Comment: I have the exact same issue. The weird part of it is that my other custom made JENKINS Kube slave agents can pull GIT just fine.  But this new agent I created, just cannot!

@apr_1985 how can I go about debugging this? Clearly it cannot be corrupted Credential SSH Key

Comment: Are they running on the same worker nodes? I would check if the agent has out bound access to your git server. Then check if the git server is in the authorised keys file or if strict host key checking needs disabling. Check if the credential has pull access to the repo you are using.